# How to run an iPad app I downloaded from iTunes in simulator

Tags: ipad

I don't have an iPad yet, but is it possible to download an iPad app using iTunes and run the app in simulator?
If yes, how would I do that?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 6):

Do you really think Steve Jobs would have made that possible?

In all seriousness, no.  Real iPhone and iPad apps are compiled for a different processor.  The iPhone simulator runs Intel code.